# ActionCable doesn't work with Unicorn in Rails production server (nginx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket, unicorn, actioncable

I have a RoR project.

However, when I use Nginx and Unicorn to run my actioncable in production server it doesn't work like it does in my development Rails environment.

The error I got is as shown in below:

> Rack::Lint::LintError: Status must be >=100 seen as integer

I can't understand the cause of error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding ENV['RACK_ENV'] = "deployment" to your unicorn config file. See this issue for more details: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26179

Answer (score 2):

I've been through the same error and the below solution worked for me.
You can upgrade your `nginx.confi` file with below configurations:

```
 location /cable/ {
       proxy_pass http://$app_server;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
```

I hope this solution helps :)